# padrino-0.14.1.1とactivesupport-5.1.1の組み合わせでhumanizeがNoMethodError

Tags: ruby

padrino-0.14.1.1とactivesupport-5.1.1の組み合わせで使っていて、padrino-adminを生成しているのですが、ログイン画面(/admin/sessions/new)を表示すると以下のようなエラーが発生して、500エラーの画面になってしまいます。

```
DEBUG -  TEMPLATE (0.0007s) /sessions/new
2017-11-07 20:23:01 - NoMethodError - undefined method `humanize' for "login.title":String:
    /Path/to/app/'vendor/bundle' /ruby/2.3.0/gems/padrino-admin-0.14.1.1/lib/padrino-admin/helpers/view_helpers.rb:43:in `padrino_admin_translate'
(以下略)
```

ネットを検索してもこのような事例はないので、Padrinoのバグではない考えており、とりあえずの対応として、view_helpers.rb の先頭に以下のrequireを追加することで動きました。

```
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/core_ext/string'
```

しかし、自分のアプリケーションの問題のために、Padrinoのファイルを編集するのも良くないと思います。他に良い対応方法があったら教えて下さい。

Comment: 英語版への質問　https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47168434/humanize-nomethoderror-on-padrino-0-14-1-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GithubのPadrinoリポジトリにissueを投稿したところ、メンテナーから現象がバグによるものであることと、現時点での対応方法について回答をもらえたので、自己回答します。

対応方法については、バグが修正されるまでは、config/initializersに以下のようなextra_requires.rbファイルを置くことで、とりあえず対応できます。
view_helpers.rbを編集する必要はありません。

```
# config/initializers/extra_requires.rb
require "active_support"
require "active_support/core_ext/string"
```

回答の原文は以下のとおりです。

--

Looks like a bug due to the ongoing effort to remove the ActiveSupport dependency from Padrino.

You don't need to update view_helpers.rb - creating a file in config/initializers should be sufficient as a temporary stop-gap until the bug is fixed.

```
# config/initializers/extra_requires.rb
require "active_support"
require "active_support/core_ext/string"
```